# How to restrict if condition to only one time execution of an sql query in java

Tags: java, sql, if-statement

I am passing through an sql query through an if statement as seen below. I was wondering how I can restrict the query from executing infinite times to just once off? I need the loop as it's constantly weighing whats on the scale and when the value is in the range of my array it executes the query but it executes repeatedly as long as the weight is in that range. Is there a way around this where once it executes it won't execute again even if the weight is still in the range?

```
 public class UsbScale implements UsbPipeListener {

    private final UsbDevice device;
    private UsbInterface iface;
    private UsbPipe pipe;
    private byte[] data = new byte[6];

    private UsbScale(UsbDevice device) {
        this.device = device;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UsbException {

        UsbScale scale = UsbScale.findScale();
        scale.open();
        try {
            for (boolean i = true; i; i = true) {
                scale.syncSubmit();
            }
        } finally {
            scale.close();
        }
    }

    public static UsbScale findScale() throws UsbException {
        UsbServices services = UsbHostManager.getUsbServices();
        UsbHub rootHub = services.getRootUsbHub();
        // Dymo M5 Scale:
        UsbDevice device = findDevice(rootHub, (short) 0x0922, (short) 0x8003);
        // Dymo M25 Scale:
        if (device == null) {
            device = findDevice(rootHub, (short) 0x0922, (short) 0x8005);
        }
        if (device == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new UsbScale(device);
    }

    private static UsbDevice findDevice(UsbHub hub, short vendorId, short productId) {
        for (UsbDevice device : (List<UsbDevice>) hub.getAttachedUsbDevices()) {
            UsbDeviceDescriptor desc = device.getUsbDeviceDescriptor();
            if (desc.idVendor() == vendorId && desc.idProduct() == productId) {
                return device;
            }
            if (device.isUsbHub()) {
                device = findDevice((UsbHub) device, vendorId, productId);
                if (device != null) {
                    return device;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void open() throws UsbException {
        UsbConfiguration configuration = device.getActiveUsbConfiguration();
        iface = configuration.getUsbInterface((byte) 0);
        // this allows us to steal the lock from the kernel
        iface.claim(usbInterface -> true);
        final List<UsbEndpoint> endpoints = iface.getUsbEndpoints();
        pipe = endpoints.get(0).getUsbPipe(); // there is only 1 endpoint
        pipe.addUsbPipeListener(this);
        pipe.open();
    }

    private void syncSubmit() throws UsbException {
        pipe.syncSubmit(data);
    }

    public void close() throws UsbException {
        pipe.close();
        iface.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void dataEventOccurred(UsbPipeDataEvent upde) {

        boolean empty = data[1] == 2;
        boolean overweight = data[1] == 6;
        boolean negative = data[1] == 5;
        boolean grams = data[2] == 2;
        int scalingFactor = data[3];
        int weight = (data[4] & 0xFF) + (data[5] << 8);

        // int phoneWeights[] = new int[5];
        // int minWeight = 142;
        //int previous weight=0;

        boolean phoneOnScale = false;
        int[] phoneWeight = {140,150};

        /*
         for(int i=0, i=Length(phoneWeights); i++) { phoneWeights[i] = minweight+i; }
         */

        /*
         * System.out.println(String.format("Weight = %,.1f%s", scaleWeight(weight,
         * scalingFactor), grams ? "g" : "oz"));
         */

        System.out.println("My Weight: " + weight);
        /*if(newweight != oldweight) {
            oldweight = newweight;
            write to db shopping list;
        }*/

        if(phoneWeight[0] <= weight && weight <= phoneWeight[1]) {
            phoneOnScale = true;
            System.out.println("Phone is on scale");
            // write one phone to table in db.
            try {
                // create a mysql database connection
                String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
                String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/smartfridge";
                Class.forName(myDriver);
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "admin");

                // the mysql insert statement
                String query = " insert into fridge (name, UnitOfSale, ContentsQuantity, department, AverageSellingUnitWeight)"
                        + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

                // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
                PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                preparedStmt.setString(1, "Eggs");
                preparedStmt.setInt(2, 1);
                preparedStmt.setInt(3, 6);
                preparedStmt.setString(4, "Milk, Butter & Eggs");
                preparedStmt.setBoolean(5, phoneOnScale);

                // execute the preparedstatement
                preparedStmt.execute();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            phoneOnScale = false;
        }
```

Comment: is there a loop on top of `if`?

Comment: @Deadpool Yes sorry the loop is contained in my main method:                'public static void main(String[] args) throws UsbException {

  UsbScale scale = UsbScale.findScale();
  scale.open();
  try {
   for (boolean i = true; i; i = true) {
    scale.syncSubmit();
   }
  } finally {
   scale.close();
  }
 }'

Comment: Simple remove loop if you don't need it

Comment: @Deadpool I need the loop as it's constantly weighing whats on the scale and when the value is in the range of my array it executes the query but it executes repeatedly as long as the weight is in that range. Is there a way around this where once it executes it won't execute again even if the weight is still in the range?

Comment: You should update the code

Comment: @Deadpool I added more above.

Comment: @jconboy Did my new answer work for you? If so can you checkmark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you can try doing is making a boolean set to false in the beginning. Then have another if loop before the query that will only run the query if it is false. Then once you have run the query change the variable to true with the loop itself.
In pseudo code

```
boolean querychecker = False
#this would have to be done outside your other loop. Maybe at the beginning of the class.
if (querychecker == False){
    do(query)
    querychecker = True
}
else {
   #whatever you want to do
}
```

Comment: I hope this can help you if you have not already figured out how to do this.